# Configure a Liquibase Gradle plugin to generate change set

Tags: kotlin, gradle, spring-data-jpa, liquibase, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to generate a Liquibase changelog from entities in the Spring Boot project. This is how my Gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
    // other plugins
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.0.3"
}

dependencies {
    val kapt by configurations

    // other dependencies
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
}
```

This is my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:${DB_PORT:5432}/${DB_NAME:test}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME:db_username}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:db_password}
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
```

I have created `liquibase.propertis`:

```
changeLogFile=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
username=db_username
password=db_password
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.example?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
diffChangeLogFile=db/changelog/changes/diff-changes.yaml
```

when running `./gradlew generateChangelog --info` output is following:

```
> Task :generateChangelog
Caching disabled for task ':generateChangelog' because:
  Caching has not been enabled for the task
Task ':generateChangelog' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
:generateChangelog (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 650ms
```

As I understand plugin isn't correctly configured but I can not understand what is wrong. It just doesn't fail and there is an existing [issue](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin/issues/30) for this on their Github page. Nothing is generated after this run can not understand what do I configure incorrectly can't find documentation even to properly understand what might be the issue Github description seems quite unclear for me.

Comment: `liquibase.propertis` should be `liquibase.properties`